# -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

In our code any exception is caught to show its details in a messageBox.
But the (in my case) nullpointer-exception doesn't contain the stacktrace elements.

So, I add '-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow' as JVM argument.
But the stacktrace elements are still missing.

Anyone know a reason why that could be?

Using Netbeans 8.2, JDK8u60

Regards.